# Recursively count the number of loops that occur in a recursive function without using a static local variable, global variable, or static function?

Tags: c++, recursion

For my recursion exam I have to write a recursive function that goes through a linked list, and removes all nodes that do not contain certain data, and count the number of nodes removed in c++. I am not allowed to use a static function, static local variable, or global variable. How do I do this?

Specifically the function used is: **int remove_except(node * & head, node * & tail)**, and it is used on a linearly linked list. I cannot find any way to count the number of nodes removed without using one of the three methods listed above.

Comment: Free clue: how does a function that's called by a caller would *return* a value to a caller, like some kind of a counter, or something?

Comment: There's no code here, just a method signature. What are we supposed to intuit from that? I'm also confused why you're passing in references to pointers.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think you're saying I should return some integer named counter, and increment it every time a loop occurs? But I don't know how to do this in a recursive function without altering the function prototype, or making a static, or global variable, both of which I'm not allowed to do.

Comment: @tadman I'm not sure why the function passes references to pointers either, it's just the required prototype, typed verbatim by the instructor.

Comment: Proof by induction: `f()` removes nodes from the list, and returns the number of nodes removed. `f()`: call itself recursively for the list after the node passed into `f()`. Then, if the node passed into this call should not be removed, attach the node back to the recursive call's list, return the same counter. Otherwise, remove the current node, and return counter+1. Mission accomplished. No, nobody will write this code for you. This is not writemycodeforme.com, this is stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm not asking anyone to write code for me; Thats why I didn't supply code. I'm literally just looking for what method can be used to return the count of recursive loops that occur without passing a count as a parameter, or using a static local, or global variable.

Comment: @BrandonT: "*Use the Force [**return value**], Luke [Brandon]*".  For each invocation of the recursive function, do the following: If the input node is at the end of the list, return 0. Otherwise, if the input node is removed, return 1 + the return value of the next invocation (using the next node as input). Otherwise, return the return value of the next invocation as-is (using the next node as input).  When all of the invocations are finished, the 1s will add up as control works its way back up the call stack to the original caller.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you so much Remy! That makes a lot of sense. I'm a recursion noob and you just saved my ass. Is there anyway I can upvote / star your post?

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't use variables or parameters, that leaves only one option - use the function's **return value**.

For each invocation of the recursive function, do the following:

- If the input node is at the end of the list, return 0.
- Otherwise, if the input node is removed, return 1 + the return value of the next invocation (using the next node as input).
- Otherwise, return the return value of the next invocation as-is (using the next node as input).

When all of the invocations are finished, the 1s will add up as control works its way back up the call stack to the original caller.

For example:

```
int remove_except(node * & head, node * & tail)
{
    if (!head) return 0;
    node *next = head->next;
    if (... /* head is to be removed */)
    {
        removeNode(head, tail);
        return 1 + remove_except(next, tail);
    }
    return remove_except(next, tail);
}
```